# Two Lie groups which are isomorphic but not homeomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, topological-groups

I am looking for an example of two Lie groups which are isomorphic as groups but not homeomorphic as topological spaces. Or, even more interestingly, a proof that two such groups cannot exist. Does anyone have an example or a proof?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are isomorphic as groups because both are vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the same dimension, but they are not homeomorphic as topological spaces because the former can be disconnected by removing a point and the latter cannot.

Comment: The proof of the first fact you quoted requires the axiom of choice yes?

Comment: Yes, if you take away the axiom of choice, there is a model in which the opposite conclusion to the OP's original question holds (it's consistent with ZF that all group homomorphisms between Lie groups are continuous).