# No homeomorphism.

Tags: group-isomorphism

Hey im looking for an exmaple of an isomorphism f between normed Spaces, where the inverse is not continous. I found some examples for continous bijective functions but its hard to imagine an example which is also linear. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are leaving off a lot of information.  You have, presumably, a function $f:A\to B$, yes?   What are $A,B$?  Sets, groups, topological spaces, topological groups, vector spaces, something else?

Comment: I also never saw a witch which was also linear.

Comment: sorry, f must be a funktion from X to Y, where X and Y are normed spaces

Comment: Then add this information to your question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis) and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060042/show-that-the-open-mapping-theorem-requires-both-spaces-to-be-complete

Comment: This may help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190707/two-lie-groups-which-are-isomorphic-but-not-homeomorphic